# How can I capture characters in a string up to the first vowel and create substring out of it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

Currently, the first part of my code works correctly. If it detects that the first character (index 0) is a vowel it stops and adds "yay" to the end of word.

The second part is intended to capture consonants up to the first vowel. This works correctly.

The problem occurs when I try to take the original word and slice off everything up to the first vowel and create a new substring out of it. This would mean that if the user inputs "hello" it should output "ellohay". I can get "hellohay" but can't figure out how to capture those initial consonants and slice them out.

```
# Pig Latinify

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']


def pig_latinify():
    state = True
    while state == True:

        user_input = raw_input("Enter a word to be translated: ").lower()

        # If the first character in input is a vowel add 'yay' to input and print.
        if user_input[0] in vowels[0:]:
            print ""
            print "Begins with a vowel." 
            pig_output = user_input + "yay"
            print user_input, "becomes:", pig_output
            print ""
        else:
            print ""
            print "Doesn't begin with a vowel."

            captured_consonants = ""
            captured_substring = ""
            new_user_input = ""

            # Capture the consonants up to the first vowel
            for i in user_input:
                if i in vowels:
                    break
                if i in consonants:
                    captured_consonants = captured_consonants + i

            # Slice user_input up to the first vowel and create a substring beginng from the first vowel until the end of the string.
                if i in consonants:
                    break
                if i in vowels:
                    captured_substring = captured_substring + i 
                print captured_substring

            # Concatenate substring of user_input with captured_consonants and 'ay'
            pig_output = captured_substring + captured_consonants + "ay"
            print user_input, "becomes:", pig_output
            print ""

pig_latinify()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex would probably be your best bet:

```
# Pig Latinify
import re

vowels = list('aeiou')

def pig_latinify():
    state = True
    while state == True:

        user_input = raw_input("Enter a word to be translated: ").lower()

        # If the first character in input is a vowel add 'yay' to input and print.
        if user_input[0] in vowels[0:]:
            print ""
            print "Begins with a vowel." 
            pig_output = user_input + "yay"
            print user_input, "becomes:", pig_output
            print ""
        else:
            print ""
            print "Doesn't begin with a vowel."

            r = re.search("(.*?)([aeiou].*)", user_input)

            # Capture the consonants up to the first vowel
            captured_consonants = r.groups()[0]

            # Slice user_input up to the first vowel and create a substring beginng from the first vowel until the end of the string.
            captured_substring = r.groups()[1]

            # Concatenate substring of user_input with captured_consonants and 'ay'
            pig_output = captured_substring + captured_consonants + "ay"
            print user_input, "becomes:", pig_output
            print ""

pig_latinify()
```

This basically non-greedily searches the string until it hits a vowel, and makes two groups of the consonants and the vowel+following string, and manipulates them accordingly.

```
$ python pig_latin.py 
Enter a word to be translated: hello

Doesn't begin with a vowel.
hello becomes: ellohay

Enter a word to be translated: hi

Doesn't begin with a vowel.
hi becomes: ihay

Enter a word to be translated: apple

Begins with a vowel.
apple becomes: appleyay
```

Comment: When you say "non-greedily" does that mean not using a loop and iterating over each index value? It does it as a "search" instead?

Comment: @lookininward Non-greedily means that it goes until the first vowel in the input, and groups that. If it was greedy, it would go until the last-vowel in the input.

Comment: @lookininward https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things for a deeper explanation.

Comment: @lookininward please mark an answer as correct if any of them here helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to drop all leading chars until you hit a vowel you can use [itertools.dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
from itertools import dropwhile
user_input = "hello"

vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"}

up_to = "".join(dropwhile(lambda x: x not in vowels, user_input))
print(up_to + user_input[:len(user_input) - len(up_to)]+"ay")
```

output: ellohay

`lambda x: x not in vowels` means we want to drop all chars until we find a character in vowels. If you want to work for upper or lowercase add the uppercase vowels to the set or switch the lambda to `x.lower() not in vowels`

Comment: Or just change the lambda to `x.lower()` ?

Comment: @JonClements, True, the OP is actually calling lower on the input string so probably a moot point but I will add it anyway

Comment: ...and `set('aeiou')` is a bit less typing :)

Comment: @JonClements,  lol it is but `{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}` might be a bit more obvious for the less well informed ;)

Comment: I don't think that's exactly the pig latin OP's looking for. He wants "ellohay" not "elloyay". But I love how succinct your solution is!

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal, indeed, not sure where I saw the other `y`, have not even had a drink yet...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Looks like you still need a drink, now it's "elloay" not "ellohay"!

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal, lol, yep finally fixed I think, time for a drink :0

Answer (score 0):

This code looks rather strange. For instance, the second  `if i in vowels:` is never reached.

Instead of this you may want to:

1. Find the position of first vowel - let it be `pos`
2. check if `pos` > 0
3. `return user_input[pos:] + user_input[:pos-1] + 'ay'`